# What does it mean when you say C++ offers more control compared to languages like Python?

Tags: c++, python, programming-languages

I am comparing C++ with Python. It is clear that C++ is much more efficient and that the C++ code compiles directly to machine code whereas in Python it is interpreted.

I do understand that Python is a higher-level language. But what difference does it make? I intuitively understand that C++ offers more "control", but what does it mean concretely? Can you give an example of things you can do with C++, but not with Python?

Comment: Write some programs with them. We could tell you but the answers won't necessarily make much sense and you'll likely learn it faster just by solving some problems with both.

Comment: I have written programs with them. I understand intuitively what it means to say that C++ has more control. I am looking for a concrete explanation.

Comment: Intuitive is all there is. As the answer below shows, the difference has more to do with common scenarios and conventional usage rather than a principled distinction. The short version is that the only absolute difference is that C++ and Python make different tradeoffs about what they make easy vs. what they make hard.

Comment: "It is clear that C++ is much more efficient" -- Define "efficient"? I'm not sure but I think the only technically accurate meaning of that word has to do with the ratio of usable output power to the input power, and while that's an important property of, say, a motor, it doesn't really mean anything in a programming context. Whereas the things that are important here, for a programming language, are much less straightforward to define or measure. Saying "X is _clearly_ more efficient than Y" without defining what you mean just sounds like soapboxing your personal opinion.

Comment: Write programs with both is not really a good answer. The question is how do they differ specifically?

Comment: @ilkkachu - in the context of this question it is VERY clear it's referring to efficiency of CPU and memory usage.

Comment: @ilkkachu The definition of efficiency in physics is work-out/work-in and this is meaningless until you define what work-out is desired.  For example an incandescent light bulb is a more efficient heater generator than it is a light source.  By analogy we can  say computation is more efficient when the same outcome can be generated with less resources.  We could also define it by how much effort a developer puts relative to an outcome, it which case Python is much more efficient.  Or vulnerabilities out over dev time in, in which C++ is clearly more efficient at generating vulnerable code.

Comment: @DavorŽdralo, no, it is not. Case in point: see the comment immediately following yours.

Comment: @DavorŽdralo and even if we somewhat agree on a rough notion of CPU and memory efficiency, it is nowhere near "clear" that C++ *is* more efficient. *Programs* written with it perhaps *can be* more efficient than "equivalent" programs written in Python, but they also *can be* way more inefficient and faulty.

Comment: All those huge PC games? There's a reason they're written largely in C++.

Comment: @FrankHopkins - again, it's obviously clear when we are talking about programming languages, that efficiency is considered between best possible results with those languages. It's like you are intentionally trying to sabotage the conversation by using the most ridiculous pedantry there is. You're not even technically correct because language always relies on context for meaning.

Comment: @ilkkachu - the comment you refer to is exactly the type of absurd pedantry that sane people should avoid. Really, definition in *physics*? Are you confused which stack this is?

Comment: @DavorŽdralo rofl, no it's not clear, that's why we have this argument. Different contexts different perspectives on what efficiency means. And speaking about pedantry, relying on context for meaning is all but a *technical* issue. *Technically* one *can* mess up a C program in more fun ways than a Python program, it's very *efficiently* allowing you to do so.^^ I grant you it is clear what efficiency roughly OP meant due to the interpreter vs. compiled argument, but the statement in itself isn't so clear cut. Especially when trying to define the language differences.

Comment: @DavorŽdralo i.e. the core difference is that you have more freedom (to write a particularly resource efficient implementation, but also to write a particularly resource inefficient implementation or a buggy one because you messed up the resource handling etc). And arguably the same instructions can be run faster or with less tooling overhead depending on your runtime context. The problem with the statement is that it's too general as a learning outcome when the topic is exactly related to the specific differences between the languages.

Comment: @DavorŽdralo, did you read it? I mean, either of my comment or JimmyJames's...? E.g. the part where he mentions the kind of efficiency of getting things done vs. spent developer time? You're free to disagree of course, but I think that's quite an important metric in programming. In some situations, getting the thing to run fast on the CPU (or, optimising the time/energy the code needs to finish a task on some computer) might be important, but that's not at all always the only relevant factor.

Comment: @DavorŽdralo so basically we argue from different perspectives at least for the part about efficiency. Yes, one can deduce what OP meant (somewhat well enough at least for casual conversation), but the sentence isn't a good language difference summary as a learning outcome in this context in our (I guess) eyes.

Comment: @DavorŽdralo, as for physics, well, at the risk of repeating myself, the issue here is that the word "efficiency" is not that well-defined in programming as it is in physics. And as FrankHopkins said, while one can deduce what the OP perhaps meant, their post also makes it seem they can only think of that one kind of efficiency, while completely forgetting about other related concepts. Not to put too fine a point on it, that seems rather.. narrow-minded.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

> Can you give an example of things you can do with C++ but not with python.

Sure. For instance, C++ gives you control over where objects are placed in memory. The programmer decides whether an object is stored on the stack or the heap - and can even control where on the heap by using a custom allocator. This can be helpful when exploiting memory locality effects to improve memory access performance.

Also, in C++, you control when an object is destroyed, which allows side effects to be attached to that destruction. For instance, if you have a C++ object for an open file, you control when this object is destroyed, allowing the destructor of that object to automatically and promptly release the native file handle. In Python, you have no control when the object is freed, and therefore have to close the file manually.

In C++, you can also perform crazy optimizations by manipulating pointers. I remember one memorable case where a program had to store a great many object references representing boolean functions, some of which were negated. Rather than storing the negation in a separate variable, they stored it in the least significant bit of the pointer, which was known to always be 0 due to memory alignment. This allowed them to cut their memory use in half. They couldn't have done this in Python.

> It is clear that C++ is much more efficient

Not necessarily: That the programmer has this control doesn't necessarily imply he will use that control better than Python does. After all, the guys that write Python runtimes are quite skilled software developers, and probably know more about low level performance optimization than the average C++ programmer.

So if you are choosing between C++ and Python, it is true that C++ gives you more control - but it is also true that C++ *demands* that control. You must manage memory. You must ensure you never use after free. And so on. Are the benefits of having that control worth spending the time to exercise it? Or would you rather have the language runtime take care of these details, so you can focus on other things? The answer will depend on what kind of software you are writing.

Comment: Python also only has 1 type of int and float. So I suppose C++ has more "control" over bytes in a number.

Comment: If you write "modern C++", you rarely do any manual resource-management. But you can, and therefore are always near enough to the chainsaw to cut your head off.

Comment: And you can "cut your head off" without actually doing any manual resource management by taking a pointer or reference to an automagically managed resource and keeping it around after said automagically managed resource is freed.

Comment: "After all, the guys that write Python runtimes are quite skilled software developers, and probably know more about low level performance optimization than the average C++ programmer." The dominent python runtime is a bytecode inrepreter with no jit and thus fundamentally slow. Even the jit-based runtimes suffer from the highly dynamic nature of the language.

Comment: But JIT runtimes do exist, and if you are writing performance sensitive code you would use those, wouldn't you? And I don't buy your argument that highly dynamic languages can not compete with C++, because speculative optimization can often reduce the performance impact of unused flexibility to near zero. For instance, unlike C++, modern JIT runtimes will inline virtual calls if they usually resolve to the same method. Likewise, if a variable usually contains a number at runtime, the JIT can speculatively compile this to a double, falling back to different code path otherwise.

Comment: @PeterGreen but that is a detail of an implementation, not something intrinsic to the language. And as for the dynamic nature of the language itself it is certainly possible to write extremely staid Python that's amenable to optimization followed by compiling ahead of time, and it's possible to (ab)use dynamic features in C++ like virtual method lookups that make it "slow". I get the argument: for most programs and most programmers C++ gives you "more control" and is "faster", but the OP seems to be asking specifically about a principled distinction, and there arguably isn't one.

Comment: @meriton there are many optimizations that can be done only in a JITter. Theoretically there are some applications that may run faster in a JITter, but in reality there's none. Apps that are compiled ahead-of-time almost always run faster that apps that are JITted

Comment: I think this is a pretty good answer, but you make it sound like there's a pretty good chance if an "average" programmer writes a program in C++ and Python, the Python one might be faster. While you're not wrong C++ isn't _necessarily_ faster, if we're playing the odds I'll certainly bet it is. Even if the programmer is just "average". And this is because the canonical CPython implementation, despite the knowledge of the people that wrote it, is terribly inefficient.

Comment: *In Python, you have no control when the object is freed, and therefore have to close the file manually.* That's just not true. Python has extra syntax for that, `with open(filename,'r') as file:` which has the same destructor semantics as C++.

Comment: *[In C++] You must manage memory.* No you don't. C++ has automatic memory which is allocated and deallocated without the programmer having a say in it. That actually affects most things. The C++ standard barely even mentions that a stack exists and it doesn't have to, so you cannot actually put something on the stack. The same goes for the heap because you don't get to decide where in the heap the memory is allocated.

Comment: @nwp the difference between python context management and C++ destructors are that destructor doesn't need special syntax from caller and works the same if object lifetime isn't bound inside the single function call. C++ standard doesn't mention stack because because there's no need to force automatic storage to be implemented as stack. It's just the common and handy way to implement automatic storage.

Comment: @OwenReynolds 3rd party libraries for Python, notably numpy, has more than one type of int or float, and almost any Python program doing any kind of number crunching will use numpy.

Comment: @PhilFrost A skilled Python programmer will know how to use numba, dask, pyCUDA and others [to calculate the Mandelbrot Set as quickly as in C (or quicker!)](https://web.archive.org/web/20200101033110/https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/How_To_Compute_Mandelbrodt_Set_Quickly?lang=en), but it's admittedly unfair to compare the average C++ programmer with a skilled Python programmer, except that it _might_ be easier to become a skilled Python programmer than a skilled C++ programmer.

Comment: @gerrit But NumPy advertises bringing the power of C (or Fortran) to Python. Isn't it a case of "oh, C++ gives more control over numbers than Python -- use the C-code in NumPy to make up for that"? The OP is asking what people _say_.

Comment: @gerrit None of those things are written in Python.

Comment: @OwenReynolds Yes, but the Python programmer doesn't need to know any C, C++, or Fortran to benefit from that power.  The most popular implementation of Python is also written in C, so most Python programmers are already "using C code", with or without Numpy.

Comment: Numpy and similar libraries are fine as long as you are prepared to work with the numbers in big chunks, the slowness of the python interpreter doesn't matter because the time spent interpreting python code is a small fraction of the overall runtime. However if you want/need to work on the individual numbers from said big block you are back to the slowness of the interpreter.

Comment: _"C++ gives you control over where objects are placed in memory. The programmer decides whether an object is stored on the stack or the heap"_ That is false. C++ is an abstraction and gives literally zero control over such things.

Comment: _"In C++, you can also perform crazy optimizations by manipulating pointers. I remember one memorable case where a program had to store a great many object references representing boolean functions, some of which were negated. Rather than storing the negation in a separate variable, they stored it in the least significant bit of the pointer, which was known to always be 0 due to memory alignment. [..]  They couldn't have done this in Python."_ They couldn't do it in C++, either. Their program had undefined behaviour. You can't randomly hold arbitrary pointers like that.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings you can legitimately reinterpret_cast to and from an int value of sufficient size, and what you do with that int value between casting from and to a pointer doesn't matter. You also can store an array of integers which are indices into an array of functions, but shifted up to give some extra bits of storage to apply the technique in either language at the cost of an indirection (or use the high bits of the int instead of the low).

Comment: Exactly. Specifically, the standard [writes](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#5): "A value of integral type or enumeration type can be explicitly converted to a pointer.
A pointer converted to an integer of sufficient size (if any such exists on the implementation) and back to the same pointer type will have its original value; mappings between pointers and integers are otherwise implementation-defined."

Comment: @PeteKirkham Sure, you can, but the OP said they manipulated the bits of a pointer, not the bits of a `std::intptr_t`. Also meriton has just literally quoted the standard that says that even this "safe" approach has only implementation-defined behaviour. It's just not the way to go about things in C++. That "it's all just bytes" is a total myth.

Comment: "storing in the least significant bit of a pointer" was intended as a concise summary. Of course the pointer was cast into a "sufficiently large integer" before accessing its least significant bit. The behavior of that is explicitly defined in the standard. Yes, assuming that the least significant bit of pointer is 0 is implementation-defined, but I know of no serious C++ implementation were this is not the case (for objects with sizeof 2 pointers). And even if the implementation did not guarantee this, you could always write a custom allocator that does.

Comment: My 2c: in Python you can also manually allocate and manage memory through low-level packages such as mmap, albeit it would be rather cumbersome. CPython implements reference counting, there is also the `del` operator and in most cases it's pretty clear when objects are destroyed/deallocated, which means you can also use/write your custom destructors.

Comment: @nwp even if the C++ standard doesn't require stack or heap to exist, you may exploit implementation-specific details that ensure you have both heap and stack. Moreover, you can create your own heap, with your own allocators and use that.

Comment: @Marandil True. "Can" being the important word here. The answer claims it's a "must".

Comment: @nwp I would argue that C++ requires you to understand the storage scope of `int x;` and that when you do `int *p = new int();` you then should `delete p;`. GC/refcount based languages might allow you to create a local variable, export a reference to it, and then use it after leaving the local scope.

Comment: @Marandil: `del` removes a binding, but it doesn't actually guarantee immediate clean up (other bindings may exist, and even on CPython, cyclic references could keep it alive until the cyclic garbage collector runs). Custom `__del__` methods have been frowned on for a long time when context management can do the job; `__del__` isn't as bad as it was (it used to be a memory leak waiting to happen pre-3.4), but it's still worse than context management (which gives guarantees across all interpreters, rather than relying on implementation details of garbage collection).

Comment: @ShadowRanger oh yeah, I know the context management is superior to `del`, I just pointed out you can do a "free" this way.

Comment: @Marandil: Right, but the point is that `del` is not a C/C++ `free`/`delete`. It's more like assigning `NULL` to, or explicitly invoking the destructor of, a `std::shared_ptr`. Sure, if you *know* it's the *last* shared pointer holding a reference to the object, that works. But there's no clean way to be sure of that, unless you literally allocated the object yourself, and never passed it to any other function (and even then, the API could have hidden caching or reference cycles that keeps it alive beyond the `del`). Context management has (close) equivalence with C++ RAII, `del` doesn't.

Answer (score 52):

> It is clear that C++ is much more efficient and that the C++ code compiles directly to machine code whereas in Python it is interpreted.

This is wrong. C++ and Python are *programming languages*. A programming language is an abstract set of mathematical rules and restrictions. It is neither compiled nor interpreted. It just *is*.

Any language can be implemented by an interpreter. Any language can be implemented by a compiler. Many languages have both compiled and interpreted implementations. Many modern high-performance language implementations use both interpretation and compilation in the same implementation.

For example, *every single currently existing Python implementation* uses a compiler:

- CPython has an ahead-of-time compiler that compiles Python source code to CPython byte code.
- PyPy has an ahead-of-time compiler that compiles Python source code to PyPy byte code, then it has another compiler that compiles PyPy byte code to native machine code (or ECMAScript when running in a browser).
- IronPython has an ahead-of-time compiler that compiles Python source code to DLR Trees, then it has another compiler that compiles DLT Trees to .NET CIL byte code, which the .NET runtime then may or may not compile to native machine code.
- GraalPython has an ahead-of-time compiler that compiles Python source code to Truffle ASTs, then Truffle takes over and compiles Truffle ASTs to JVM byte code or native machine code, in the first case, the JVM may then in turn compile the JVM byte code to native machine code.

So, three out of four will eventually compile to native machine code, and even the odd one out still has a compiler.

On the other hand, there are interpreters for C++ such as CINT and Ch. And there is Cling, which is an interpreter based on a JIT compiler based on the Clang ahead-of-time compiler …

> I intuitively understand that C++ offers more "control" but what does it mean concretely?

How do you define "control"?

Some people claim that C++ is "closer to the hardware" or that it allows you to have "fine-grained control over how things are laid out in memory". This is not actually true, however. C++ is specified in terms of an Abstract Machine. There is nothing in the specification guaranteeing that this Abstract Machine corresponds to the real machine that the program is running.

There are C++ compilers targeting ECMAScript and the JVM. How is a C++ program running inside a JavaScript interpreter inside a JVM inside a VirtualBox VM "close to the hardware" and a Python program running on a microcontroller that doesn't even have an OS is not? C++ also has some rules about how implementors are allowed to optimize memory layout, which means that the actual memory layout may not be what you think it is.

And when you say "closer to the machine", then what "machine" are you talking about? C++ may be close to a PDP-11, but it is most definitely not close to a [Reduceron](http://cs.york.ac.uk/fp/reduceron/), and Python is closer than C++ to an [Azul Vega 3](http://cpushack.com/2016/05/21/azul-systems-vega-3-54-cups-of-coffee/).

Some people say that C++ has more "control" because all of its default abstractions are "zero overhead", and any abstractions that are not zero overhead are opt-in. But that is not true either: for example, you cannot opt out of pointers, they are always there. I have worked on a machine that has no pointers, and both C and C++ are *very* slow on that particular machine, because they have to effectively run inside an interpreter that simulates pointers, and since pointers are most heavily used in high-performance code, that has a *huge* impact.

Instead of pointers, the machine has a concept of *object references* in the CPU itself. Unfortunately, there is no native Python implementation on this machine, but there is a native JVM, and on that particular machine, Java was significantly faster than C or C++.

Now, you might say all of those are weird niche machines, surely C++ is close to the PCs we are all actually using? Well, I would argue that this is only technically true, but not for the reason you think it is.

C++ is not "close to the machine" because of anything in C++. Rather, it is "close to the machine" because CPU vendors like Intel and AMD are working very hard to make their CPUs work the way C and C++ expects them to. So, in some sense C++ is *not* close to the machine, rather the CPU vendors are making the machine close to C++.

> Can you give an example of things you can do with C++ but not with python.

I can't, because there is no such thing.

Both languages are *Turing-complete*, meaning you can compute any computable function on the natural numbers.

Both languages are "Tetris-complete", meaning you can process user input, interact with the environment, interact with the OS, interact with libraries written in C or other languages.

And yes, there has been an experimental Operating System written in Python.

Comment: "*C++ is not "close to the machine" because of anything in C++. Rather, it is "close to the machine" because CPU vendors like Intel and AMD are working very hard to make their CPUs work the way C and C++ expects them to.*" Since those processors predate C++, wouldn't it make more sense to say that C was designed to mimic certain processors, and that the success of those processors encouraged the proliferation of particular assembly tropes that prioritize design that is appropriate for C?

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed answer. When I say "C++ is closer to machine", I am only quoting what many people say. Would you say that it is not true or that it is a matter of opinion. I understand that there is no general answer because it depends on the specific machine and compiler/interpreter. However, If I may rephrase: Is there something that C++ does better or more efficient than python where the reason can be broadly attributed to what people refer to as "C++ being closer to hardware", perhaps something like having better control over memory or time complexity.

Comment: `A programming language is an abstract set of mathematical rules and restrictions.` I agree with this in theory. In practice many languages don't even have de jure standards (eg Python). Of those that have standards, programs are often written against implementation instead of the standard (eg Haskell vs GHC). A extreme minority of commonly used languages have well-defined mathematical semantics (only SML comes to mind).

Comment: +1 for teaching me the term "Tetris complete"

Comment: The definition of a language is also coupled with the implementation. Some language features are impossible to implement efficiently.
Almost all of the (quite interesting) examples are extreme outliers. Almost all code does not run on Reduceron or Azul Vega 3 or inside a Russian Doll of VMs. People say things about "performance" and "control" because they are true in the common case.

Comment: About Turing Completness and being able to do "anything" - while you can compute anything, you cannot **do** anything in language that is TC. For example I am able to compute anything using BF, but I am not able to send TCP request without external help. It is important to differentiate between these concepts.

Comment: @JustinRaymond _"In practice many languages don't even have de jure standards (eg Python)."_ - I would argue that Python does, in fact, [have a de jure standard](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html).

Comment: FYI you can add Jython to the list and compare it with your examples of C++ targeting the JVM

Comment: "I can't, because there is no such thing." -

There most definitely is, if you don't argue the semantics/theoretical nature, but look at the practical problem. When people say "Python" they usually don't mean the set of the rules that define the grammar, but one or a few of the main implementations. You'd be hard pressed to write, day, real-time OS in any of them.

Comment: Similarly, the argument about Turing completeness is somewhat pointless in reality. It only says that you can implement any abstract algorithm, but if you requirements are about interacting with OS APIs or underlying HW in some specific way it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Hauleth: That's why I mentioned "Tetris-complete". I first heard Idris described as "Pacman-complete" and I thought it was a brilliant way to classify a programming language, but I wanted something that sounded closer to "Turing-complete", and so I came up with "Tetris-complete". I only discovered later, that other people had been using the term before me. There is no formal definition of the term, but intuitively it means "can be used to implement Tetris", i.e. can take user input, can react to external events, can interact with external libraries, the OS, hardware, etc. In keeping with the

Comment: … tongue-in-cheek nature of the naming, Idris was first proven "Pacman-complete" by implementing *Asteroids* and saying that "the proof that Asteroids reduces to Pacman is left as an exercise to the reader".

Comment: @DanM.: That's why I mentioned "Tetris-complete". (See preceding two comments.)

Comment: @NicolBolas: I'm not (just) talking about the ISA. I'm also talking about the evolution of CPU design. For example, consider cache misses: the cost of cache misses is the cost of an individual cache miss multiplied by the number of cache misses. So, obviously, there are two ways to reduce the cost of cache misses: you can reduce either of the two numbers. Mainstream CPUs reduce the number of cache misses using various techniques such as branch prediction, memory prefetching, speculative execution, etc. The thing is, most of those optimizations don't work for languages like ECMAScript, Python,

Comment: … Ruby, Java, Objective-C, Kotlin, Scala, PHP, Perl, etc. In other words, they don't work for a *huge* amount of code that is written today. The Vega 3 CPU OTOH reduced the cost of an individual cache miss by having very clever custom memory controllers and out-of-order execution. A Vega 3 could have 20000 outstanding memory fetches and still make progress. However, you have a limited budget of transistors (and engineers), so you can't really put both optimizations into a CPU, you have to choose. And vendors choose #2 because it benefits C-like languages and high-performance code is written in

Comment: C. Thus, C gets ever more faster, which means even more high-performance code is written in C which means CPU vendors get forced to optimize their CPUs even more for C, and so on. The Azul Java Compute Accelerator and its Vega 3 CPU are a good example of language-compiler-OS-hardware-software co-design. In this company, they *explicitly* designed the CPU so it would work together with the compiler and of course the compiler was designed specifically for the language (JVM byte code in this case), the memory architecture of the machine was designed to match the Java Memory Model, and so on.

Comment: In Azul, the co-design was an *explicit* goal of the company, but this is only the most obvious example. The same thing is actually happening between the language design of C, C++, etc. the compiler design of GCC, Clang, ICC, etc. and the design of mainstream AMD64, ARM, MIPS, etc. CPUs. It is just a lot less explicit and driven by market forces instead of a deliberate overarching design philosophy. But there is nothing inherent in C++ that makes it "close to the machine", it is a *result* of the "accidental" hardware-compiler-language co-design implicitly happening.

Comment: @SouravGoyal: The only thing that comes to mind is that the C++ library specification *explicitly* specifies time complexities for many data structures and operations. The Python reference, on the other hand, does not do so. So, it is for example illegal for a C++ library vendor to provide a `sort` function that is not O(n log n), whereas that would theoretically be allowed for Python. However, while the Python library reference does not *explicitly* spell out such constraints, it is *implicitly* understood that data structures and algorithms should have their "normal" complexities, and thus …

Comment: … any Python implementation that ships with bubble sort as the implementation of `sorted` would simply be ignored by the community.

Comment: @PeterM: I am not familiar enough with Jython unfortunately. The last time I looked at it was 15 years ago or so. Back then, it had no JIT, but I remember that when Oracle hired the two JRuby lead developers, which lead to enormous performance improvements in JRuby, the JRuby lead developers also started helping out with Jython, and eventually convinced Oracle to fund Jython as well, and one of the things they wanted to do was implement a JIT. But I have no idea whether that actually happened before Oracle changed its focus again and stopped funding Jython and JRuby development.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: "*I'm not (just) talking about the ISA.*" Well, neither did I, so I'm not sure who you're responding to. "*it is a result of the "accidental" hardware-compiler-language co-design implicitly happening.*" That perspective ignores the history of C. Remember: CPUs that "happened" to promote the C style of CPUs predate the C language. The C language was *made for* those CPUs, not the other way around.

Comment: @marcelm I used de-jure (by law) to distinguish languages which have a formal process for declaring what the language is (such as C++ or ECMAscript). As opposed to python where "python" is still very much "what CPython does". The fact the linked document is versioned with CPython releases supports this.

Comment: One could also mention the old [iapx432](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_iAPX_432)

Comment: @Hauleth This is simply not true. If BF is turing complete, nothing prevents me from implementing TCP/IP in BF and interfacing with networking hardware.

Comment: @idmean that's not what Turing completeness means, and the exact reason why Tetris-completeness was invented. It would be interesting to know if it's possible to implement Tetris in non Turing complete language...

Comment: @ojs Sure it does. Turing-completeness means the language can be used to simulate any turing machine. It is assumed today that something is computable if and only if there exists a turing machine that can compute the problem (Church–Turing thesis). Since TCP/IP and interfacing with network cards obviously can be done ("computed"), there exists a turing machine that can do that. And since such a turing machine exists, this can be done in any turing complete language. (You are confusing what a language can do vs. its default execution environment.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag I'm not really familiar with Jython myself.  I only know about it because the Ignition HMI by Inductive Automation is written in Java for platform independance and uses Jython (v2.7 %#$&@#$)  as its scripting language. (i just looked and Jython is stuck at 2.7, with v3+ only an idea)

Comment: @idmean A Turing Machine *can't* interface with network cards. It's operation is entirely specified by it's starting conditions. You need *a sequence* of Turing Machines that operate on pairs of `packet, previous result` to do TCP/IP.

Comment: @Caleth Agreed, my phrasing might be misleading. But still any turing-complete language can simulate any sequence of turing machines (there is a turing machine that could) so my point is still valid.

Comment: To clarify: A turing-complete language can be used to program any other application you could possibly have provided there is a suitable compiler, hardware etc. for that language.

Comment: I don't understand why you are putting Python and C++ on the same page. The whole answer seems defensive. It's clear that C++ is designed around the low-level details of real machines, while Python is not. Here's something you can't do in python: specify memory order semantics on load and stores. It's also **very false** that Intel or AMD model their CPUs around C++ or that their uarch optimizations don't work for interpreted languages. Python targets a different environment than C++. Not a race. Prove me wrong: write a pure Python 3.9 (no C, only builtin libs, assembly allowed) bootloader :)

Comment: @Margaret Umm... now you go and write a pure C++ bootloader. Now if you're going to use assembly in there, well by that logic I'm then certainly allowed to use C modules in Python as well. Given that the whole asm definition in C++ is completely implementation defined and need not even exist, it's also impossible to use that code in anything but one specific compiler and version.

Comment: @MargaretBloom because this is a competition of intellectual supremacy. Everyone except maybe the OP knows the answer, and it's much more fun to be technically correct and prove wrong anyone who attempts a honest answer. And no, C++ isn't a good low level language but it's the best that we have.

Comment: -1 for being counterproductively pedantic. You write "this is wrong", and sure, you can ignore practice and argue all programming languages are theoretically equivalent. But you damn well that's not what people mean when they make the statement in the question. The statement is about practice, not theory.

Comment: The page you linked about the Azul Vega 3 says "each core is a classic 3-address 64-bit RISC processor".  It sounds like you could target a C++ for it quite easily.  It unfortunately doesn't go into any detail of its hardware(?) support for garbage collection, though, and yes that would be left unused by many C++ programs.  But being optimized for running tons of threads (many weak cores), it would be total garbage for normal Python implementations, which are very dependent on single-threaded performance.

Comment: @Voo: You could probably pull off a simple pure-C++ bootloader for UEFI systems.  I assume you mean without any inline asm, but you can hard-code absolute addresses in C++ if needed.  You can also make arrays of a machine code and cast them to function pointers; that's pure in the sense it can compile anywhere, but of course is UB to execute in ISO C++.

Comment: @Peter If it's undefined behavior it's not valid C++. Never looked into the UEFI spec, but that'd be pretty cool if you could actually configure a system without any special assembly instructions.

Comment: @Voo: ISO C++ isn't the only C++.  In a specific C++ implementation (we're making a bootloader here...), it can explicitly define the behaviour of things C++ doesn't.  e.g. `g++ -fwrapv` defines the behaviour of signed integer overflow.  Or GNU C++ by default defines the behaviour of union type-punning, like C99 does.  An implementation may also de-facto define the behaviour of casting an array to a function pointer.  Re: UEFI: yes, a bootloader is a "UEFI application" loaded by firmware from the EFI boot partition (FAT), built with a normal compiler with the UEFI SDK headers, apparently.

Comment: *the cost of cache misses is the cost of an individual cache miss multiplied by the number of cache misses.* - Not quite true; modern CPUs have significant memory-level parallelism.  e.g. Intel Skylake can track up to 12 incoming / outgoing cache lines in flight at once.  JIT-compiled languages like Java are not totally dissimilar to AoT C++ machine code.

Comment: Also, out-of-order speculative execution reduces the *cost* of data cache misses by trying to hide some of the latency (independent later work is still happening while that load and instructions waiting for that data are blocked) It mostly doesn't reduce the number of misses.  Maybe some if future loads from the same line run now instead of after it's evicted again, in some really bad scenario where you touch more than 8 lines that all alias the same set inside an inner loop.  But OoO exec can only "see" a window of maybe 100 to 200 insns ahead.

Comment: C++ may be specified using an abstract machine, but it actually runs on real machines, which give you "control".

Comment: @PeterCordes Indeed, because the Standards only seek to define the behavior of portable programs, there are some constructs which 99% of implementations process in the same useful fashion, but which the Standard nonetheless characterizes as UB to allow for the possibility of platforms where the common behavior would be less than ideal.

Comment: @JustinRaymond: The Python language standard and the CPython reference interpreter are both documented on the same site, but that doesn't mean that the language standard described there only describes CPython. In the language standard docs, they describe the features needed to implement a Python interpreter of the specified version of the standard (which is kept in sync with the releases of the CPython interpreter out of convenience). They're also careful to clarify when behaviors are implementation details of CPython, vs. guarantees any compliant interpreter must provide.

Comment: @JustinRaymond: If you want a "language defined by the interpreter", Perl before Perl6/Raku is a much better example; the Perl interpreter was *the* single reference for what constituted Perl the language, and reimplementing a new interpreter basically meant maintaining compatibility with source code, not documentation. Python has had several alternate interpreters over time, which follow the Python language standard while relying less, or not at all, on CPython the reference interpreter, and cases where the reference interpreter violates the standard are treated as bugs in the interpreter.

Answer (score 15):

I really like the existing answers separating language from implementation. That's very precise. Yet I tend to be obsessed with the practical differences, or at least I've been forced to with the teams I've worked with. I've had to be *that* guy, and it's not always so fun.

And at least from that practical perspective, C++ is a more *explicit* language. *More explicitness* usually translates in practice to *more control*. For example, C++ is statically-typed (explicitly typed), while Python is dynamically-typed (implicitly typed).

That sort of explicitness tends to translate not only to more control but more practical control so far. In theory, a more implicit language could eliminate the runtime overhead that is typically associated via exhaustive static analysis, but that tends to never happen in practice (at least among popular implementations of interpreters and compilers of languages). It's extremely difficult to do, and such an implementation would likely take longer to compile than even most C++ compilers which already tend to be notorious for their build times. So typically in practice a lot of that implicitness translates to more machine code which imposes costs at runtime, whether it is with dynamic (implicit) types or implicit memory management via GC. And that's why I'd say, so far, that the explicitness of a language like C++ tends to translate to more control (not theoretical, but practical) over the resulting machine code with most implementations over a more implicit language like Python.

Of course, more control, even if it's only in practice and not theoretical, isn't always a good thing. Giving humans more control also tends to open up more room for errors. Control can also be used for nefarious purposes, like implementing malware.

> **Edit: Can you give an example of things you can do with C++ but not with python.**

To keep the answer simple, I would suggest for any language to look at your standard library or framework. Is it all implemented with the same language? I tend to think digging into the answer to that question will reveal the language's limitations or lack thereof, especially when you look at something like standard Python modules implemented in C for reasons other than performance. There are many cases with higher-level languages where the language is incapable, with its constructs, of talking so directly to hardware or the underlying operating system.

**Edit: on `auto` in C++.**

I got a very nice question about `auto` and was tempted to write a verbose explanation with code in the comments, so probably better to address that here. Immediately I would point out that:

```
auto x = expression;
```

... in C++ is not comparable in terms of implicitness/explicitness to:

```
x = expression;
```

... in Python, if we look beyond the similarity of the syntax and the requirements of `auto` for that expression's resulting type to be 100% unambiguous at compile-time (which means the human C++ programmer/communicator must be sufficiently explicit in the expression to the extent of total disambiguation). In Python, that expression on the right-hand side is allowed at the level of language specification to be completely ambiguous to the compiler with respect to what type `x` will have after compiling it (which generally translates, in practice, to more machine code that must be executed at runtime to evaluate the resulting data type). The type of `x` along with the expression in Python's case could vary based on runtime inputs like the contents of a file that should only be loaded at runtime, or what button the user clicks in a GUI, or types into a command prompt. With Python, we can do things like:

```
def func(runtime_input):
    # Return a string or an integer based on runtime input.
    if runtime_input:
        return "hello"
    else:
        return 123;
```

... where even a single caller can provide different values of `runtime_input` based on, say, what a user types into a command prompt at runtime. Python allows that degree of implicitness to the point of complete language-level ambiguity of evaluating expression types that cannot possibly be resolved, and disambiguated, at the time the program is compiled. And that's the type of implicitness/ambiguity vs. explicitness/disambiguation we find between dynamically-typed vs. statically-typed languages that I think matters most at the language level and compiler design level when we're talking about practical human control over machine code and runtime behavior. Ambiguity generally translates, in practice, to the compiler having to insert more machine code (such as additional runtime branches) and having to make more assumptions on the part of the lack of explicitness of the human communicator.

With C++, we even have keywords like `sizeof` and `alignof` and `decltype` whose mere presence in the language means that every single expression written in the language requires sufficient explicitness on the part of the human programmer, and sufficient information provided to the compiler, that it can always evaluate the size, alignment, and resulting data type of any valid expression written in the language before the program is executed without a single exception to the rule. No matter how deeply we recurse into templates and uses of `auto`, we are never allowed that level of implicitness where the compiler is unable to deduce the type unambiguously before runtime. That heavy requirement on explicitness is generally going to translate, in relative (not absolute) terms, to *relatively* increased control on the part of the human over the resulting runtime behavior over a language that doesn't require such explicitness.

**Implicit vs. Explicit**

I should clarify in this answer that when I'm talking about explicitness vs. implicitness, it might get confusing given how we think in English or any other human language. But that's completely irrelevant. This question made me think like a compiler (sometimes brilliant but also sometimes dumb, as anyone who has looked at disassembly output from their profilers will discover -- we compilers are autistic savants able to determine that your bitwise loop is basically a `popcnt` only to trip over our untied shoelaces and take 5 minutes to retie them while confusing ourselves). And that's my reference point. I'm an idiot/genius compiler (and anyone who has spent enough time profiling and diassembling their compiler's output will realize they are an odd mix of genius and special education material). And I'm talking like a compiler when I say what this human person is implicit about this (ambiguous) and explicit about that (unambiguous). As humans we can say, "Oh there, it's obvious I meant that," or "Or here, it's obvious what they mean." It's very easy to think we're being sufficiently explicit as humans, but I'm a dumb compiler, and I don't use unsupervised machine learning to optimally compile your code. And it's not always so obvious unless you really told me what you mean and required to do so by your language. Because otherwise, I sort of need to guess, idn't it? And you might not have much control over what I guess for you. At the very least I might guess correctly towards the outputs you wanted but maybe not towards the instructions. Do you want more control over me? Pick a language that tells me more explicitly what to do, even if that's tedious, and makes me guess/assume less. But be careful what you wish for. Or don't wish for it, and the majority of people might be better off for it.

Comment: One important difference between C++ and Python is not only that typing is static vs dynamic, but that types themselves are static in C++ and dynamic in Python. You can have static types and implicit typing, and that would allow ahead-of-time complete type deduction. With dynamic types (that is, types that can be changed throughout runtime), complete ahead-of-time type deduction is equivalent to solving the halting problem.

Comment: Your phrase "statically-typed (explicitly typed)" isn't quite clear to me. How would you characterize C++'s `auto foo = "foo"`, Java's `var foo = "foo"`, Standard ML's `val foo = "foo"`, etc., all of which use [type inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference) to give `foo` a static type that doesn't appear explicitly in the source code?

Comment: @ruakh C++ type deduction still requires that `auto` deduces to something reasonably explicit. I could see how that could inflate compile times recursively if put to extensive use. But the focus of the language still wants to map it to some type through an expression. At the very least a variable is not allowed to change type on the fly.

Comment: @ruakh For example, let's look at `sizeof` or `alignof`. They'd be extremely difficult to implement in languages we'd call "dynamically-typed".

Comment: @DemonCode: What I'm saying is, I don't understand what you mean by "explicit". In "dynamically typed" languages like Python, where values rather than expressions have "types", the type of a value often appears explicitly in the source code; and in statically typed languages like C++, where expressions do have types, the type of an expression often does *not* appear explicitly in the source code. What does "explicit" mean to you, if it doesn't mean "appearing in the source"?

Comment: Counterexample: [Julia](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Memory-layout).

Comment: @rhakh statically typed means the type is known at compile time (and this is true of things like auto or var, it just takes a bit more working out; its still explicitly in the source code, just not right next to the variable). Whereas in a dynamically typed language it isnt. In fact (if things like duck typing are involved) it may be completely different types each time a method called. The same variable may hold a string on tuesday, a number on Wednesday and a complex object on thursday (although more likely; 2 different objects that both happen to have a `foo()` method)

Comment: @RichardTingle: I understand static and dynamic typing. What I *don't* understand is what DemonCode means by "explicit", or what you think "explicitly in the source code" means. Static typing does *not* require the type to be explicitly indicated in the source code -- at least, according to any mainstream sense of the word "explicit". Maybe the two of you mean something like "rigid", "fixed", or "determined in advance" instead?

Comment: @RichardTingle I think it's incorrect to associate static typing with explicit typing and dynamic typing with implicit typing, even just in practice. For example, it's my understanding that perl is both dynamically and explicitly typed. Types are only checked at runtime, but also specified in source (by symbols, not names). However, Haskell is statically typed, and can be fully implicitly typed. Types are checked at compile time, but don't need to be specified in the source; they are implied.

Comment: @ruakh I edited my answer to respond to you about `auto` since my answer was getting quite verbose in the comments!

Comment: The equivalent of your python `func` is by the way valid in many functional languages. The return type of the function would be sum type of string and int and its `string`or `int` value would be accessed through pattern matching. Doing this unintentionally in Scala is great way to get some confusing compiler errors.

Comment: @ojs They produce a compound data type of some sort, like a tuple? I tend to be strongly in the static typing camp at least in imperative languages since I've often felt like those compiler errors, even when they can be incredibly confusing with generics and type inferencing, have prevented things from turning into bugs at runtime. I might be far more comfortable though with dynamic typing in functional languages given the extreme layer of predictability that immutability and value semantics tend to provide.

Comment: @DemonCode https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union

Comment: @ojs I see! I'm familiar with tagged unions in languages like C++ but it's the first time I heard of a case where a compiler can implicitly generate one fixed based on the combination of return types a function can output. That sounds pretty cool, and at least much lighter weight in some cases (ex: only requiring the memory of the largest data type involved) than a "store anything" sort of type under the hood.

Answer (score 8):

Language comparisons are always source of heated discussion and painful confusions. Giving "more ***control***" does not mean anything by itself:

- Both languages have very similar ***control*** flows.
- Python being a dynamic language, it allows to change control at runtime and even trick the inheritance tree:  is it more ***control*** because C++ doesn't allow it? Or is it less control, because the execution flow is free to follow some unexpected path?

In you comparison, use clear and precise wording to describe what you really want to compare.  If with "***more control***" you mean in fact "***more predictability***", i.e. when you need to avoid surprises like when controlling a nuclear power-plant or a fighter jet,  then C++ will give you more control, since the language definition allows more compile-time check,  which reduces unexpected situations at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

Mostly it's not the language itself but the implementations.

For embedded programming where the ultimate control is required, there is absolutely nothing that requires processors to have registers mapped to memory addresses, and C++ standard is pretty explicit that memory space does not need to be flat and while pointers can be converted to integers and back, the conversion can be arbitrary. In practice microcontrollers often do have memory mapped registers and one can access them from C++ just by casting the address as integer to pointer. For the same access in most languages usually considered high level, you'd need to implement an extension that would typically (but not necessarily) be implemented in C or assembly and called over foreign function interface that uses C calling convention.

For memory layout, the standard leaves a lot implementation-defined but in practice there are only a few well known ways that implementations do actually use. Cross-platform and cross-compiler portability can be tedious, but often in the cases where you need this control you're stuck with single HW and toolchain anyway.

Compiling to assembly isn't required by standard, as seen with Bitcode, and inline assembly is likewise a common non-standard exception. However, sometimes everything is not neatly memory-mapped and you need platform-specific instructions or compiler can't figure out the exact instructions you need for the most optimized algorithm implementation. In these cases simple integration with assembly is a huge benefit. With simple in-order non-superscalar processors just looking at the generated assembly is a useful tool for understanding what the program does at low level.

Finally, something that is a part of C++ standard and what was uncommon for languages that have objects as familiar from C++, Java, Python and others, is the control over object lifetimes and the ability to acquire and release other resources together with the memory (or more generally, have side effects to releasing the object). This allows more explicit handling of resources than garbage collection where resources are released *eventually*, and requires less work from client code than for example IDisposable in C# or Python context management. In practice modern C++ can handle almost all lifetime management, but if you really need to roll your own, it is possible.

The other feature in C++ standard that is unique among commonly used object languages is customizable memory allocation. Placement new allows you to skip default allocator for any object, and standard template library allows you to use custom allocator for anything. This, together with some common non-standard features, is useful for a range of things from placing higher level objects over memory mapped registers to implementing optimized memory layout and low overhead allocators.

Comment: But for embedded there are ***non-standard*** extensions, right? For example, `67 = 129;` means write 129 to the raw (low) memory address 67 - typically for changing hardware registers or using memory-mapped I/O (normally ***assigning something to a constant*** would result in a compile error). That is, it is completely outside of any C++ standard (and C standard for that matter).

Comment: Why would one need non-standard language extension, and why that particular choice? You can already do it in standard C++: `*reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(67) = 129u;`. The only non-standard part is how does the compiler implement converting an integer that hasn't been cast from pointer into pointer.

Comment: Of course normally you'd cast to `volatile unsigned char*` to make sure the store happened exactly once because the very act of storing is a visible side effect.  Now that C++ has a thread-aware memory model and `std::atomic`, MMIO is basically the only real use-case for `volatile`, other than sometimes in micro-benchmarking, or [roll-your-own atomics in a few existing codebases.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557979/when-to-use-volatile-with-multi-threading/58535118#58535118)

Comment: Good point about volatile. I left it out because the comment was about direct access to raw memory location.

Comment: +1 Was tempted to go into memory management as well. I got all hung up on dynamic typing maybe because I recently implemented an interpreter for a DSEL where I considered dynamic typing heavily, but it just seemed so difficult to optimize away the extra layer of branching without the programmer specifying what types are involved.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: 67=129 would be an error in every variant of C I know of.  `*(char*)67 = 129;` would be the traditional way of performing a write to address 67, though some compilers today would require `*(char volatile*)67 = 129;` in order to process the code reliably. Because such constructs aren't portable, and the C and C++ Standards only concern themselves with portable constructs, neither really specifies what code should do; compilers which are designed to be maximally useful for embedded programming tend to treat them consistently without regard for whether the Standards require that.

Answer (score 0):

In C or C++, the Standard defines the behavior of something like:

```
int read_int(int *p) { return *p; }
```

as "If `p` is a pointer to an object whose effective type (for C) or dynamic type (for C++) is `int`, then return the value of that `int` object.  Otherwise behave in any fashion the implementation sees fit.

Many implementations however, at least if suitably configured, would define the behavior as "use the platform's natural method to perform an `int`-sized load from the address given in `p`, interpret the bit pattern as an `int`, and return it", without making any effort to distinguish situations where the effective/dynamic type is `int` (meaning the Standard would require that behavior) versus those where the Standard wouldn't require such behavior but they see fit to behave in such fashion anyway.

The amount of "control" offered by a particular C or C++ implementation depends on the extent to which the designers see fit to reliably process non-portable constructs in a documented manner characteristic of the environment.  Neither language requires implementations to give programmers much control, but most implementations can be configured to do so, at least with optimizations disabled, and quality implementations can do so even with useful optimizations enabled.

Comment: Defining UB doesn't give the programmer control, it just enables "programming to the implementation instead of the interface" by poking random things until it seems to work. Also, it is a strait-jacket for the compiler, eliminating many chances for optimization, thus appreciably slowing correct programs. Of course, you can always disable optimization and there are generally other options to make different UBs defined.

Comment: What do you mean "seems to work"?  The C Standard uses the term Undefined Behavior to actions which some or even most implementations should define, but may not be practical for *all* implementations to define in all cases.  According *to the authors*, UB among other things "...identifies areas of possible conforming language extension: the implementor may augment the language by providing a definition of the officially undefined behavior."

Comment: As for being a strait-jacket, that is only true of compilers whose authors refuse to recognize that the Standard was intended to say that compilers need only presume that *seemingly-unrelated* objects might alias if they are of the same type, not that they should be willfully blind to relationships between objects.  Suggesting that a compiler that sees a `T*` converted to a `U*` and can't understand everything that's done with it should allow for the possibility that any `T` which the pointer might target could be accessed in ways it doesn't understand between the time of the conversion and...

Comment: Yes, the standard mentions that UB is where an implementation can define things if it has good reason. But it really only should if the cost is outweight by the benefit of defining that small specific bit that specific way, not just because "I hate UB".

Comment: ...the next use of the storage as a `T` that is either in the context of the conversion or a surrounding context, is hardly a "strait jacket", since such conversions would generally be rare outside cases where such allowance would be necessary.

Comment: Regarding strict aliasing, yes, it would be convenient if the compiler could automatically detect all instances it is violated and make provisions for *healing* them without impacting performance everywhere. Doing it accurately in the general case reduces to solving the halting-problem, but many small constrained instances are solvable given full information. Where to draw the line though, and how to document it? One thing is certain, it will make the compilers job yet more complicated.

Comment: @Deduplicator: You may feel that implementations should only define things if the cost is outweighed by the benefit.  I'd accept that as fair if one accepts that such a burden would be very easily met on implementations where the cost was zero, and that compatibility with code written for such implementations is for many purposes a major benefit.  The Committee made no effort to specify all of the cases where all existing implementations for commonplace platforms would process constructs 100% consistently and doing otherwise would have been seen as obtuse, so failure to identify such cases...

Comment: ...doesn't imply that general-purpose implementations for commonplace platforms shouldn't extend the language to support them.

Comment: //Where to draw the line though, and how to document it?//  If a compiler's "gaze" when looking for potential relationships among objects is as broad as its gaze when trying to reorder or consolidate accesses, and if the compiler treads cautiously around suspicious actions it can see but not fully understand, and volatile accesses were treated as potential memory clobbers (but not hardware barriers), the vast majority of code which would otherwise require `-fstrict-aliasing` would no longer do so.  This isn't rocket science.

Comment: If the fact that the Standard had specified that the rules are meant to indicate when *seemingly-unrelated* items may alias, and that the ability to recognize object relationships is a quality-of-implementation matter outside the Standard's jurisdiction, the language would be in much better shape today.